# Reference dictionary values

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe, df with columns headers A, B , C, D

can I reference these headers from this dictionary?

```
dic={'key1':['A','B'],
key2: [C,D]}

df[key1[0]]
```

giving the output of just column A?

```
   A
0  44
1  44
2  44
3  33
```

Comment: You would use `df[[dic[key1[0]]]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but you need

```
df[dic['key1']]
     A    B
0  NaN  NaN

df[[dic['key1'][0]]]
     A
0  NaN
```